# Gmap Error "Javascript is required to view this map" when embedding the node in another node

Tags: location, google-maps, nodes

In my drupal 6 site, I use finder embedded in a node, to search for another node.
When user select a result the node is loaded in the same page.
The final structure is

- parent node

  - finder embedded
  - parent node description

    - resulting node

Everything works fine, except that the Map loaded in the resulting node is not displayed.
I get this error "Javascript is required to view this map".
Obviously I've checked what's wrong, and I've seen that the required JS are missing (gmap.js, marker.js, etc..).

How can I force GMap to load js if they are missing?
Why do you think this is happening?

**UPDATE**

The problem is related to Ajax.
If I take the same scenario and hit Enter instead of Find, the request is made without using Ajax and the map is shown correctly.
Using the Find button (Ajax request) the problem persist.

Any solution?

Comment: Which Drupal version do you use? And can you tell us how the resulting node is loaded? Do you have multiple nodes like the parent node, or is it there just one on your site?

Answer (score 1):

`GUnload` is part of the Gmap API. Are you loading the Gmap js files served by Google?

The error would happen if the JS file from Google is:

- Missing.
- Has not been parsed when the code giving the error is executed.

*To give a more thorough answer more details are needed.*

**Update**

The Gmap module is a bridge to the Gmap JS API that Google has created. The actual Gmap JS API is not included in the module itself but is served by google. It's included using the following line:

```
drupal_set_html_head('<script src="'.
  check_url(url('http://maps.google.com/maps', array('query' => $query))).
  '" type="text/javascript"></script>'
);
```

The error you are getting, it is caused by the lack of the above JS file, or because it's loaded after the gmap module JS code is run.

Comment: No, the files are the one included in the GMap module. http://drupal.org/project/gmap

Comment: @notme You are wrong, see my updated answer.

Comment: where should this be added? into template.php or in the tpl file?

Comment: @notme It should be added to the head of the site along with other JS and CSS file declarations. See [`drupal_set_html_head`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_set_html_head/6)

Comment: I've tried, but I get a syntax error in maps.

Comment: It seems like the problem is related to Ajax request and not to JS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should force gmap to include JS in your parent page (or, to test, every page). Insert this in your hook_init() or in your template.php:

```
_gmap_doheader();
```

The reason is that, if you include JS by AJAX, it may be not ready when Gmap uses it.

Edit: I looked at the code again, and changed the code.

Comment: hook_init should be in my template.php file?

Comment: I've changed the code. You can put in your theme (preprocess_page) or hook_init of a module. Check http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/6 for what is a hook.

Comment: I think in this way the js are correctly loaded, but I still get "GUnload is not defined" pointing at this "if (Drupal.jsEnabled) {
$(document).unload(GUnload);
}"

Comment: Ok, the problem with GUnload was I modified the GMap module. Reinstalling the -dev version made the error disappear. But the map still doesn't show.

Comment: The problem is not related to JS, but to Ajax request. I've updated my post with more details.